# How to sniff which Java class (library) is writing to System.out?

Tags: java

The problem is either tricky or simple (not sure yet):

The project that I'm currently involved with has a bit too many logging libraries. We have log4j, sl4j, logback and who knows what else...

One of these is logging something to `System.out` and I've run out of ideas on how to find out which one and when...

I'm thinking about something like "putting a breakpoint" on sysout but I don't know if that's even something possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: What IDE are you using? You could try putting a breakpoint on the first line of your `main` method (or wherever the program's entry point is).

Comment: Intellij 2019.3

Comment: You could try putting a breakpoint on the first line of your main method (or wherever the program's entry point is).

Answer (score 5):

You can redirect `System.out` to a custom `PrintStream` that throws an error or logs it in a file. You'll have to manually go through the stacktrace and look for the offending method.

To create it:

```
PrintWriter pw = ...;
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out) {
  public void write(int b) {
    super.write(b);
    /*try { throw new Error(); } 
    catch (Error e) { e.printStackTrace(pw); }*/

    //Edit: Jeff Wang's answer is a better approach since it doesn't
    // throw an exception and just prints the stacktrace
    new Exception().printStackTrace(pw);

    //You could also write to stderr
    Thread.dumpStack();
  }
};
```

To change `System.out`:

```
System.setOut(ps);
```

If you set this at the start of your program, this'll throw an error whenever a library prints to `System.out`, catch it, and write to a file (or somewhere else). You can always format it better if you want.

This isn't a great solution beyond testing, because it involves throwing an exception every time you write a single byte (you could override the other `write` method if you wish, though) and because you need to manually go through the stacktraces. In production, you'd want something else.

Edit: Throwing an exception is unnecessary. You can do `Thread.dumpStack` or `new Exception().printStackTrace`, as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62584468/11882002) by Jeff Wang suggested.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend this? It seems like a perfectly reasonable way to instrument `System.out` calls.

Comment: @dimo414 Because it throws an error instead of letting the program continue as is. It's only okay for testing purposes, not when you want to log which libraries are logging via stdout

Comment: You could instrument it to do anything else you wanted, like write to a file or to stderr instead.

Comment: I suggest editing that first sentence to remove your reluctance to recommend. Instead, put a note at the end cautioning that they remove the instrumentation before deploying to production.

Comment: @user I forgot to add that I'm running an org.junit unit test so it perfectly fine to throw an exception :)
Your approach seems quite promising although I've put the code in the unit test constructor (together with `System.setErr(ps)` just in case) and nothing happens :/ (i.e. the output is still on the console but the exception is not being thrown).

Anyways, it's quite late, I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: No need to throw-and-catch, just use `new Exception().printStackTrace()`.

Comment: I personally prefer the other solution (from Jeff Wang). No need to throw and catch an exception.

Comment: Nice answer using `System.setOut`.

Comment: @PawelGorczynski Does it still not work for you? Try overriding a different method, like `write(byte[] b)` or `println`

Comment: @user Actually I managed to figure out the problem by classic analysis but for the sake of science I can try when I have a bit of time

Answer (score 5):

I've used this before on err, to see the actual root cause (instead of the ...and more)

```
    PrintStream o = new PrintStream(new File("A.txt")) { 
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
              super.write(b);
              IOException ie = new IOException();
              ie.printStackTrace(); //don't throw this!
        }
    };
```

and set it like user mentioned above.  It's a different method then the one he used, I'm not too sure what the difference is, I just remembered that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options:

1. Step through your code with a debugger, as @hev1 suggested. You should be able to set a break-point right on `System.out.println()` (though remember there are other methods you may need to add breakpoints to as well). Especially for a test this is likely the easiest and least-invasive approach.
2. Instrument `System.out` by pointing it to a custom `PrintStream` implementation via [`System.setOut()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream)) that's implemented however you see fit, as @user and @Jeff Wang suggested. You can throw an exception or [log a stack trace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) to manually inspect the call stack, or do something more clever like [inspecting the call stack](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()) at runtime.

   Note that, unlike the other answers, you'll want to capture a reference to the original value of `System.out` before replacing it. I think the "real" out/err instances will be lost forever if you don't :)
3. You *may* be able to [configure a `SecurityManager` to control stdout/stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62584518/113632). I'm not yet sure whether this is possible out of the box, but presumably you could use `System.setOut()` as above to register a `PrintStream` that queries a `SecurityManager`. Basically this is just a more enterprise-scale version of #2. This is probably not necessary unless you intend to *enforce* who can write to stdout/stderr, but it's worth mentioning an option :)

Comment: Great summary answer.