# Is it possible to use SecurityManager to control which classes can write to stdout/stderr?

Tags: java, securitymanager, java-security-manager

I'm curious if it's possible to restrict who can write to `System.out`/`System.err` using a `SecurityManager`. Looking at [`System.java`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk14/file/6c954123ee8d/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l2022) this doesn't appear to be possible out of the box, but perhaps there's another layer I haven't looked at?

If it's not possible out of the box, is there a reasonable pattern for implementing a custom security check using `System.setOut()`/`System.setErr()`?

Comment: No but you can require the `RuntimePermission("setIO")` to call `setOut()/setErr()`, as stated in the Javadoc.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne that's sort of the opposite problem. Certainly if you wanted to lock down stdout/stderr you'd want to restrict that too, but the default stdout/stderr permits any caller, which isn't desirable in this circumstance.

Comment: Create your own delegating `PrintStream` which does check the if the caller has some specific permission.